# Two groups of checkboxes, if first one is checked second can not be

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have two "groups" of checkboxes (although the first group only contains one checkbox), but if user checks the checkbox from the first group I want to restrict the ability of checking the checkboxes from second group...

```
<div>
  <h3>First group</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group1" />If checked, checks all the checkboxes in 2nd group</label>
  <label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Second Group</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="group2" />1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="group2" />1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Show some code of what you've done.

Comment: You might want to add the JavaScript and JQuery tags to your post, it'll get more attention. But have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: instead of using checkbox use radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a simple jQuery script to solve it.
initially it didn't exactly do what I wanted it to do, but I've managed to work around it with php as I had to make sure that if someone checked the checkbox from the second group that it didn't go to the database.

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
             if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
                 $("#checkbox2").hide();
             } else {
                 $("#checksbox2").show();
             }
         });
```

As for php I simply used a ternary operator to make sure that if checkbox with id checkbox1 is checked then I want to ignore the rest of the checkboxes...

```
$smnrs = !empty($_POST['all']) ? explode(';', $_POST['all']) : $_POST['seminars'];
```

in this case $_POST['all'] refers to the first checkbox that if clicked it hides the div holding the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <h3>First group</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group1" id='Grp1'/>If checked, checks all the checkboxes in 2nd group</label>
  <label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Second Group</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio Grp2" value="1" name="group2" />1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio Grp2" value="1" name="group2" />1</label>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#Grp1').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        { 
            $('.Grp2').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.Grp2').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```